# Writing a permutation as a disjoint cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having a lot of trouble with this notation still.. I've been trying to work on practice problems

$\beta = (1  3 2 5)(4 2 5 6 7)(1 8 7 2)(2 9 4 6)$

Let me start by trying to compute where $1$ gets sent to overall.
In the first cycle (2 9 4 6) 1 gets sent to 1 so $1  \mapsto  1$
In the second cycle (1 8 7 2) 1 get sent to 8 so $1 \mapsto 8$
In the third cycle (4 2 5 6 7) 8 get sent to 8 so $8 \mapsto 8$
In the fourth cycle (1 3 2 5) 8 get sent to 8 so $8 \mapsto 8$

So overall $1\mapsto 8$? is this right? I'm so lost can someone please help me.

Comment: Typesetting: use `\mapsto` or `\to` to produce $\mapsto$ or $\to$ respectively instead of using `->` which produces $->$

Comment: Thanks for the tip, just fixed it

Comment: Yes, $\beta[1]=8$.  Similarly $2\mapsto 9\mapsto 9\mapsto 9\mapsto 9$ and $3\mapsto 3\mapsto 3\mapsto 3\mapsto 2$ etc...  You might opt to instead of running through each element in order, run through the elements according to the most recent final result.  So you learn that $1\mapsto 8$  Then find what $8$ maps to, then find what that maps to, etc... until you arrive back at where you started and that is one of your disjoint cycles.

Comment: @Aldrec yes, you are doing fine.

Comment: @JMoravitz when I write the permutation in wolfram to check my answer it sends $1 \to 3$ though

Comment: Some authors prefer to use the convention that the product of permutations is applied right to left while others prefer to use the convention that the product of permutations is applied left to right.  It is my experience that right-to-left reading is more common which mimics the notation used for function composition.  $\sigma\circ\tau=\sigma\cdot \tau$ is a lot more easy to remember than $\sigma\circ\tau=\tau\cdot \sigma$.  It is possible that wolfram is set up to read the permutations from left to right instead.  Match whatever convention your book/professor uses.

Comment: @JMoravitz One last thing i get that$8 \to 7$ and that $7 \to 4$ but then when I try and compute where 4 maps to I get that it maps to 6 and that maps to 7 which can't be right.

Comment: To be clear and hopefully avoid confusion, I will use $\beta[x]=y$ to denote that after everything is said and done $\beta$ maps $x$ to $y$ and will write a chain of $\to$'s to keep track of where it maps according to each individual permutation in the product that makes up $\beta$.  We have $8\to8\to7\to4\to4$ so $\beta[8]=4$, not $7$.  We have $4\to6\to6\to7\to7$ so $\beta[4]=7$.  We have $7\to7\to2\to5\to1$ so $\beta[7]=1$, etc... So, we learned that $\beta[1]=8,\beta[8]=4,\beta[4]=7,\beta[7]=1$ so we have the cycle $(1,8,4,7)$ as a part of the disjoint cycle decomposition of $\beta$.

Comment: I'm making so many mistakes... Thank you for helping me clear this up. I'm just gonna have to keep working through these.

Comment: You seem to be confusing yourself with $\to$ either meaning that an individual permutation from the product that makes up $\beta$ sends one element to the next or it meaning that it was the final result for that element when considering *all* permutations making up the product.  To that, I'd recommend using different colors or different symbols to keep track of which arrow is used for what purpose.

Comment: @JMoravitz Alright I got $(1 8 4 7)(3 2 9 5 6)$ would this be correct"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct and is one among many correct ways to write it.  If we wanted to write it in the canonical fashion we might choose to have the smallest for each cycle appear at the end and have the smallests in increasing order, so in your case $(8471)(95632)$.  There is a unique way to write it in canonical fashion and there are some nice results you can prove when considering them written in this way, though nothing immediately related to what you are working on right now.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you so much for helping me clear this up!